# Passing POST parameter to WEB API2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have two different model need to be passed to web api. those two sample model are as follow

```
 public class Authetication
 {
     public string appID { get; set; }
 }

 public class patientRequest
 {
     public string str1 { get; set; }
 }
```

so to get work this i have created a 3rd model which is as below.

```cs
 public class patientMaster
 {
     patientRequest patientRequest;
     Authetication Authetication;
 }
```

and to pass the data i have created following jquery code

```
var patientMaster = { 
    patientRequest : { "str1" : "John" },                                       
    Authetication  : { "appID" : "Rick" } 
}


$.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:50112/api/Patient/PostTestNew",
          type: "POST",
          data: {"": patientMaster}
        });
```

and to catch this i have created following method in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostTestNew(patientMaster patientMaster)
{
   return " .. con .. ";
}
```

**My Problem is**

whenever testing i am getting `patientMaster` object but i am not getting any data `Authetication` object nor `patientRequest` object

I also tried to pass contenttype:json in jquery but it does not work

can some one help me on this?

Comment: Try using the _exact_ same name in your `data`-property in your jQuery function as your ActionResult. In this case: `data: {patientMaster : patientMaster}`.

Comment: tried it but same effect ... getting patientMaster object but i am not getting any data Authetication object nor patientRequest object

Comment: And if you add `dataType: "json",` to your ajax-call?

Comment: thn also its same result

Comment: Okay, and if you simply use: `data: patientMaster` (but keep the dataType etc.).

Comment: ya i tried it also i tried json.stringify but dnt know y it is not able to give data in Authetication object nor patientRequest object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76536/discussion-between-dhaval-and-benjamin-todts).

Comment: @Dhaval why is your class name lowercase.

Comment: @Phill     well i have written this whole sample api and JS things very quickly so might have some missing standards but thanks to point out ... can you pls give some link for generalize naming standard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were pretty close. I added a [FromBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute and specified the content type. I'd also make the properties in your `patientMaster` object publicly accessible.

patientMaster object:

```
 public class patientMaster
 {
    public patientRequest patientRequest { get; set;}
    public Authetication Authetication { get; set;}
 }
```

API Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostTestNew([FromBody]PatientMaster patientMaster)
{
    return "Hello from API";
}
```

jQuery code:

```
var patientRequest = { "str1": "John" };
var authentication = { "appID": "Rick" };
var patientMaster = {
      "PatientRequest": patientRequest,
      "Authentication": authentication
};

$.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost:50112/api/Patient/PostTestNew",
         type: "POST",
         data: JSON.stringify(patientMaster),
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json",
         traditional: true
});
```